# Error Handling: Skipping list items that do not exist

Tags: python, error-handling, arcgis, arcpy, try-except

I've got a script that lists the feature classes and fields in SDE database.  The python module arcplus creates a list of feature classes:

```
#Create list of feature classes on ArcSDE
mylist = arcplus.listAllFeatureClasses("Database Connections\\Connection to oracle.sde")
```

while the function arcpy.ListFields creates a list of fields for each feature class.

```
#dictionary of featureclasses and fields
    ns_dict = dict([(list_entry, [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(list_entry)])for list_entry in mylist])
```

This works great unless I don't have read access to the fields of a particular feature class.  It then returns something like:

```
IOError: "Database Connections\Connection to oracle.sde\POLITICAL.LANDS\POLITICAL.DISTRICT_LANDS" does not exist
```

For each instance of "IOError Some Feature Class does not exist" I'd like to skip to the next feature class in  my_list.   I haven't found a try/except block with this that works.  Or maybe something completely different is more appropriate?

Comment: `try: ... except IOError: pass` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

If `arcpy.ListFields(...)` raises an exception it will obviously kill that entire list/dict comprehension.  You need to wrap it around something that would handle that to return what you want.  I would try something like

```
def list_fields(list_entry):
    try:
        return arcpy.ListFields(list_entry)
    except IOError:
        return []
```

Then the dictionary construction would look something like

```
# dictionary of featureclasses and fields
ns_dict = dict(
    ((list_entry, [f.name for f in list_fields(list_entry)])
        for list_entry in mylist)
)
```

Note that I have changed your list comprehension to a generator expression, to save on memory and execution time.  Also you can use dict comprehension if you have python >2.7, which would look like this:

```
ns_dict = {
    list_entry: [f.name for f in list_fields(list_entry)]
        for list_entry in mylist)
)
```

Comment: This throws TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Whoops, missed the part where the result will iterated through - I updated the return value.